# -bash command not found error when trying to run autopep8

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line, autopep8

I can't seem to figure out a solution to this...

I've installed autopep8 on my Mac OSX 10.10.5 running Python2.7 using the following:

```
$ pip install autopep8
```

However, when I try to run any `autopep8` commands on a file like this:

```
$ autopep8 --in-place --aggressive --aggressive testfile.py
```

I get this:

```
-bash: autopep: command not found
```

I've tried to confirm that `autopep8` is installed by the following:

```
>>> try:
...     import autopep8
...     print "this is installed"
... except ImportError:
...     print "no module"
... 
this is installed
```

I've also uninstalled and reinstalled both `autopep8` and `pep8` a few times, to no avail. What else should I try or what did I not do correctly?

Answer (score 5):

You have to fix your `~/.bashrc` with :

```
export PATH=/full/path/to/autopep8_executable/dir:$PATH
```

then:

```
exec bash
```

to reload the edited file

You can figure out where the dir is using :

```
find ~ -name autopep8
```

Comment: find is returning the following path: `PATH=/Users/vader/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/autopep8` and in the `autopep8` folder I'm seeing two files: `_autopep8` and `autopep8.plugin.zsh` - which should I include in the `export PATH ...`?

Comment: This seems not the right dir. The dir should contains an eXecutable named `autopep8`

Comment: You're talking about a `autopep8.exe` file?

Comment: Are you using windows or linux ? An executable can be a binary or a text file (a script) having eXecutable bit (unix rights)

Comment: So not `autopep8.exe`

Comment: Right. I was trying to verify whether or not you noticed I specified Mac OSX in my post.

Comment: I don't use MacOsX but it shouldn't different from linux

Comment: Does this look right? `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/autopep8.py` ?

Comment: Possibly yes, try this out

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. What helped me was just uninstalling pep with:

```
pip uninstall autopep8
```

and then installing it again with:

```
pip install autopep8
```